# WCF HttpPost not valid json string

Tags: c#, json, wcf, validation

I'm trying to call a POST method on my WCF service, from a website. How ever, the WCF service complains the json string is not valid.

WCF Service method:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "reserve/batteries", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
public bool ReserveBatteries(ReserveModel values)
```

Method calling the POST, from the website:

```
var stations = TempData["Stations"];
string jsonStations = JsonHelper.SerializeJson(stations);

HttpWebRequest httpWReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:49288/reserve/batteries");

UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
string postData = "{\"Stations\": " + jsonStations;
postData += ", \"User\": \"" + User.Identity.Name + "\" }";
byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

httpWReq.Method = "POST";
httpWReq.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
httpWReq.ContentLength = data.Length;

using (Stream stream = httpWReq.GetRequestStream())
{
      stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWReq.GetResponse();

string responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

I am using Newtonsoft json libary, to serialize.
The json string I am trying to send to my service are:

```
{
    "Stations": [
        {
            "BatteryStorages": null,
            "CreatedDate": "2013-06-06T00:00:00+02:00",
            "Description": "Aalborg City",
            "Edges": [],
            "ID": 3,
            "IsActive": true,
            "IsOperational": true,
            "Reservations": [],
            "StationLat": 57.02881,
            "StationLong": 9.91777,
            "StationMaintenances": [],
            "StationType": null,
            "Title": "Aalborg",
            "TypeId": 1,
        }
    ],
    "User": "user1"
}
```

I have validated this with [JsonLint](http://jsonlint.com/) and it says it's a valid string.

Unvalid string (according to JsonLint), which WCF accepts:

```
{
    "Stations": "[
         {
             BatteryStorages:null,
             CreatedDate:\"/Date(1370469600000+0200)/\",
             Description:\"Aalborg City\",
             Edges:[],
             ID:\"3\",
             IsActive:\"true\",
             IsOperational:\"true\",
             Reservations:[],
             StationLat:\"57.02881\",
             StationLong:\"9.91777\",
             StationMaintenances:[],
             StationType:null,
             Title:\"Aalborg\",
             TypeId:\"1\"
         }
     ]",
     "User": "user1"
}
```

The exception thrown from WCF:

> There was an error deserializing the object of type RestfulAPI.Resources.ReserveModel. End element 'Stations' from namespace '' expected. Found element 'item' from namespace ''.

How can this be? Why are WCF complaining it's not valid when jsonlint (and others) say it is.

Edit:

```
[DataContract]
public class ReserveModel
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Stations { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string User { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you try sharing the `ReserveModel` class between the client and server (or duplicate it on the client) and then serialize that one with Newtonsoft? Just noticed your last edit and it got me thinking.

Comment: I'm not really sure how. Afaik Newtonsoft doesn't take type parameters, with the method I'm using `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);`

Comment: Deleted my answer, since it's not very helpful. Will try to make a test later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your Model objects are not in the correct format.

To create the correct JSON classes from your JSON you could use [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) or if you have, for example VS2012 update 2, you could copy your JSON and paste the JSON as classes (Edit -> Paste Special > Paste JSON as classes).

You will have to remember that for example DateTime objects have to be delivered in a certain way WCF supports. More information on this can be found [here (msdn - WCF JSON serialization)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412170.aspx). To dodge this problem you can just type the variable to string and convert it at a later time.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, solved the problem! I just need to figure out now, how to wrap the date "2013-06-06T00:00:00+02:00" inside a "new Date()"

Comment: If your model wants the date as a DateTime from your JSON, you could type it as a string. That way you won't have to escape and convert to the required format. This does allow you to create another property which converts the string to a DateTime. It's not the 'best way' but allows you to create less complex JSON. Something like `public DateTime DateName { get { return DateTime.Parse(YourString) } }`.

Comment: Thanks, that would be a possible solution. How ever, since I'm using Newtonsoft to serialize my json, I'm able to specify what date format I want by `JsonSerializerSettings` - http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/DatesInJSON.htm